# Remove /forum/forum from URL in vBulletin

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, vbulletin

I am using vBulletin 5.0.3 in my site. I installed it in a directory `forum` but after installation the URL of pages look like `http://example.com/forum/forum/page`

How can I change this to
`http://example.com/forum/page`